# Did the IBM 7030 "Stretch" influence the design of PL/I?

Tags: ibm360

The IBM 7030's fixed-point arithmetic model was unusual: binary numbers could have any number of bits from 1-64. Similarly, PL/I's FIXED BINARY data type has a variable number of bits. On the other hand, the first PL/I implementation was on System/360, with its now-familiar byte/halfword/word/doubleword arithmetic. PL/I's arithmetic is unnatural on such an architecture.

So, why did IBM choose that model? When PL/I was formulated, the 7030 was IBM's most advanced machine. Did PL/I's designers see the 7030 model as the future, despite the 7030's failure as a product?

Comment: PL/1 allows the programmer to specify both integer and float variables with any number of *decimal or binary* digits, and the default was decimal not binary. Since floating point decimal hardware was as rare as hen's teeth I think the language design was just an attempt to cover every possibility rather that map only specific hardware. Certainly in the workplace where I used PL/1, everyone wrote "float(6)" or "float(16)" (decimal),  rather than the longer "float bin(31)" and "float bin(63)". (IIRC it was 31, not 32 - unless some weird 32-bit hardware implemented *unsigned* floating point!

Comment: Of course S/360 did support both binary and decimal fixed point arithmetic, and declaring something like a loop counter as "fixed(5)" (i.e. decimal) instead of "fixed bin(15)" was a disaster in terms of performance because of the endless binary-to-decimal conversions generated.

Comment: @alephzero Erm, for one, the 360 used HEX float, but more important, why should a decimal loop counter be converted to binary over and over - or at all? A `SP counter,=PL1'1'` does not ask for any conversion, but quite nicely decrements the counter and delivers a condition code when reaching zero.

Comment: @Raffzahn PL/I did a lot of crazy things that only made sense if you delved into the arcane type conversion rules. It was a vast swamp of possibility with a few poorly marked paths connecting the high ground.

Comment: Keep in mind that when PL/1 was designed, there were all sorts of exotic bit lengths around.

Comment: @tofro The same was true for Fortran, but it went the more reasonable route of having `INTEGER` represent whatever the hardware's natural integer was. `INTEGER` expressions yielded type `INTEGER`. This rarely caused trouble: I did quite a bit of Fortran development on 36-bit Multics with 16-bit Nova computers as the target. You might claim that `FIXED BIN` did the same in PL/I, but it really didn't because of all the ways the conversion rules could bite you. There was a tremendous culture of sharing Fortran programs, but PL/I spawned no such culture. *Practical* portability was important.

Comment: It's probably the *exact opposite* of portability that was meant here "I want to define *exactly* what I mean" - Something we can't quite understand today, but when the chance of your program running somewhere else was practically 0%, I can at least somewhat grasp (It's of no use, but we're being precise).

Comment: @Raffzahn - I've never heard the 360's float format described as "hex float" - it's always been described as a binary format but with a base-16 exponent.

Comment: @tofro not sure, I would think it is to make sure that a port delivers exactly the same result. With INT being a machine specific format, border effects like overflow happen at unpredictable values, depending machine. If defined as FIXED BINARY (10), it always delivers the same result of an operation, no matter what machine it's compiled. Thus it's portable. Performance is not a portability criteria.

Comment: @Raffzah Nope. Consider that every implementation of PL/I is allowed to limit the precision of an intermediate expression in an implementation-dependent way. Then consider that the precision of intermediate expressions is difficult to predict because the rules are so arcane. C is not *perfectly* predictable, but it's far more transparent here than PL/I.

Comment: @Raffzahn The fact that S/360 float was base 16 has nothing do to with the PL/1 specification of how many *bits* are in the floating point number. It is perfectly legal in PL/1 to declare something apparently nonsensical like "float bin(1)".  How are you supposed to store a sign, a mantissa, and an exponent all in one bit? The answer is that the "1" is the *minimum number of bits for the implementation-defined storage size.

Comment: @JohnDoty I can tell you hours and hours of stories about exactly the same issues of ported C programs. Except with C we usually had a hard time to find any rule or at least a manual noting the internal precision used. Not to mention vastly inefficient code - like multiplying an 8 unsigned by two only after turning it into 16 bit and then running a multiplication - all on an 8bit CPU. I guess there is at least a C based story of handling problems for every PL/I based you have. But that's not relevant, as the question isn't about implementations and their quirks, but the language, isn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn "why should a decimal loop counter be converted to binary over and over - or at all?" Well, I was being a bit careless, assuming that "every programmer knows" loop counters are often used as array subscripts. And AFAIK the S/360 instruction set only used binary data for addressing memory.

Comment: @Raffzahn PL/I on an 8 bit CPU would have been worse. PL/M wasn't so bad, but it *didn't* have the arcane type system. And, of course, the PL/M compiler was written in Fortran for *practical* portability.

Comment: @alephzero ?? Somehow I do not see the point you try to make. A variable declared as DECIMAL does not need to be converted for calculation (as you claimed) or passing it to a function. If the programmer uses it with implicit or explicit conversion, then it's not the languages job to argue with what was written - isn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn You still haven't answered the simple question "I give you `FIXED BIN X;`, what is the type of `X/3`?" Easy to answer for C: `int x; x/3` has type `int`.

Comment: @JohnDoty you're aware, that CP/M (not exactly the least used OS) as well as other DR programs were written in PL/M? But my example was about real world C compilers generating such crap. So like with all of your criticism of _real existing_ PL/I compilers, which I do not argue about at all, it stays that these are issues of the compiler, not the language. One can not blame a language definition for poor implementation. And at least as of now, the question is still about the language,not any specific implementation.

Comment: @Raffzahn I take it you only have theoretical knowledge of PL/1. And you don't seem to realize the difference between fixed decimal/binary *variables* and fixed decimal/binary *constants.* A constant like "1" is a fixed decimal constant, but was *optimized* into the fixed binary constant "1B" by the compiler. AFAIK the S/360 instruction set has no instructions that use decimal constants for address calculations.

Comment: @Raffzahn Of course. Killdall wrote both the PL/M compiler and CP/M. I wrote some interesting things in PL/M, but its great advantage over PL/I was that its type system was like C: simple, directly adapted to the hardware, without arcane rules **intended** in **theory** to achieve portability, but that **in practice** fought against it.

Comment: @JohnDoty I did not answer on purpose, as that question is made in a way to open up a philosophical discussion, which will not clear up anything, as both ways follow valid reasoning. With growing experience about programming it becomes clear that there is not a single best way, and one should become able to take a step back see past the daily routine.  Regarding the theory/practice part, there is not much based on the philosophical side but practical implementation. If a compiler sucks, it sucks regardless of language.

Comment: @Raffzahn Oh, the logic behind "X/3" is perfectly *valid*, but leads to a useless and confusing end. Utility is what counts. PL/I's arcane type system was designed in a way that **forced** the implementations to suck. PL/M and C avoided this problem by abandoning the arcane type system.

Comment: @alephzero Not sure why you try to mix in more and more non related issues. Your original point was about a decimal counter in a loop. The /360 implementation I worked with does not covert it to binary (unless told so) but used decimal instructions. Now for claims about theoretical knowledge in PL/I, your might want to revisit your comment saying _'apparently nonsensical like "float bin(1)". How are you supposed to store a sign, a mantissa, and an exponent all in one bit?'_ you might ave forgotten that the precision does not define storage size of all parts, but only the mantissa.

Comment: @JohnDoty see, and that's exactly the philosophical part here. you prefer one way, others prefer another. Just that is not what the question you asked is about, or is it?

Comment: @Raffzahn But again, this brings up the question of why smart people made that philosophical decision. Face it, it was a failure, PL/I is a fringe language. Was the 7030 a factor?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126751/discussion-on-question-by-john-doty-did-the-ibm-7030-stretch-influence-the-des).

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR:

> The IBM 7030's fixed-point arithmetic model was unusual: binary numbers could have any number of bits from 1-64. Similarly, PL/I's FIXED BINARY data type has a variable number of bits.

Coincidence. PL/1 simply uses an abstract, non machine specific way to define the entities it handles - like any good HLL should do.

---

> System/360, with its now-familiar byte/halfword/word/doubleword arithmetic.
> PL/I's arithmetic is unnatural on such an architecture.

I do not really see a point of being 'unnatural' here. PL/I is supposed to be a high level language, usable on various architectures. So why should it add machine specific data types - possibly several of the same kind (like INT2, INT3, INT4) - when it can define the needed precision in an abstract way?

C did go the 'simple' way of using machine types leading to a pletoria of data types with overlapping meaning, unclear implementation and lots of pitfalls when porting programs. I still get sick when just thinking about some header files I had to read over the years trying to cope with this mess.

PL/I mechanics instead allows a clear definition what a programmer wants in a value. It's a clear and machine independent structure of

- Basic Representation : BINARY / DECIMAL
- Sign handling: ​SIGNED / UNSIGNED
- Scaling: FIXED / FLOAT
- Mode: REAL / COMPLEX
- Precision as number of digits

The result is a machine independent definition that allows portage of programs between vastly different architectures without the need to rewrite anything - seems great for a HLL, doesn't it?

Comment: In practice, quite difficult to use. Things like being careful to never let arithmetic promote precision beyond what fit in a register. I recall writing a lot of `fixed bin(17)` declarations to avoid expensive, extraneous code. Telling learners "never, ever, use `/` to divide fixed point, always use `divide`". All kinds of gotchas. C was such a breath of fresh air after that: just give me data types that behave simply, efficiently, and predictably.

Comment: @JohnDoty It seems you issue is about performance of code generated and twisting compiler behaviour. In that case Assembler should be considered, not a language with portability in mind. Something C was notoriously bad at. Of course it pays to use data definitions that match the basic operations provided by a machine - but it only pays out for that specific machine.

Comment: C was absolutely not bad at portability compared to PL/I. When UNIX first came out, it was rapidly ported to a variety of architectures with little difficulty (compare to Multics). But I never saw a PL/I program that was practical to run on both GE/Honeywell and IBM hardware. You *had* to tune your code to the specific machine in PL/I, but C doesn't need that except in relatively rare corner cases.

Comment: @JohnDoty Rare corner case? 12 vs. 16 vs 18 bit Int vs. long vs. short was anything but not a rare corner case. It was daily porting crap. Exactly because there was no clear type system like in PL/I. In PL/I tuning was only needed for performance, not for function. In all cases I encountered PL/I was way less an issue than C. C only became _kind_ of portable after all major architectures became more C compatible. Still, the problems have never been eliminated, only covered by many layers of 'best practice'

Comment: Then why did all the *practically* portable C programs out of Bell Labs and Berkeley dominate the space that PL/I was targeted for?

Comment: I would argue that C's type system is *much* clearer than PL/I's. Quick, without consulting a manual, if I give you `FIXED BIN X;`, what is the type of `X/3`?

Comment: @JohnDoty The same way because McD prevails - cheap and ready available. Same with C and Unix. When one gets the compiler and tools in source, for free, it's easy to invest a lot of time to get it somehow to run (emphasis on somehow). Especially if your department is cash strapped anyway. And the same repeated with the C64. Withotut any doubt a mediocre machine with next to non existent support - but dirt cheap, perfect for people with more time than money.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126626/discussion-between-john-doty-and-raffzahn).

Comment: I don't think this answer really addresses the question. We know that the 7030 worked, but failed spectacularly as a commercial product. We know that PL/I worked, but failed (less spectacularly) as a commercial product. Defending the variable bit count idea as sensible doesn't address the question: clearly, both the designers of the 7030 and PL/I, who weren't stupid, thought it sensible. The question isn't whether or why they were wrong, but was there an influence?

Comment: @JohnDotyThen the question is faulty in what it asks for. Something not being an influence can not be proven for anything that happened later than the postulated influence. The main point here is that there is no need for an influence of some (already at that time) exotic machine when the basic idea, as communicated in all documentation, is to be universal and not based on specific implementation. (The only, albeit weak, argument that can be made against the 7030s variable bit length is that precision > 64 bit is allowed - and of course that this as well works with float)

Comment: It's entirely possible that there are early documents referring to planned implementations on variable word length hardware. Some who recall the discussions may still be alive.

Comment: "The result is a machine independent definition that allows portage of programs between vastly different architectures without the need to rewrite anything" Cue hollow laughter from anyone who actually tried to do that for non-trivial application code. It simply didn't work. We tried, more that once, with several different target machines and compilers. The success rate was exactly zero (in binary or decimal).

Comment: @alephzero Then it would be interesting to see they analysis **why** is didn't work. Especially if it's due the language, or specific differences in implementation due different compiler?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. (Ref the [meta discussion “*Can we do something to discourage ‘armchair history’ answers?*”](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1031/278).) Just because you or I would design the language that way regardless of the hardware (and, in fact, my toy language for modern machines _does_ work this way, despite no hardware influence), that doesn't mean that's what happened.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 the first point is about a claim, which has no foundation beside the OP's assumption - quite of an 'armchair historian' thing, if you like that term. Not every random fantasy claim can be debunked by some (more or less authoritative) source - this doesn't make it true in any way.  This is where common sense must prevail. The second (after the divider!) is about the rather tedious claim of being 'unnatural' to a /360 - isn't the whole point of a HLL is to be not machine specific? C is, as shown many times, a bad example, as it stems from B which was, on purpose, machine specific.